Next js app router-page uses more resources and sends more requests when it is a server component
My page uses more resources and sends more requests when it is a server component. Here is my code:
import SectionHero from '@/app/(main)/(landing)/(components)/SectionHero'; // server component
import SectionPlans from '@/app/(main)/(landing)/(components)/SectionPlans'; // client component
import SectionReferences from '@/app/(main)/(landing)/(components)/SectionReferences'; //server component
import MetaHead from '@/components/MetaHead'; //server component
import PageLoadingWrapper from '@/components/PageLoadingWrapper'; //client component
import SectionWrapper from '@/components/SectionWrapper'; // server component

import SectionBlog from './(components)/SectionBlog'; //client component
import SectionFeatures from './(components)/SectionFeatures'; //server component
import LandingContent from './(components)/SectionHero/LandingContent'; //server component
import SectionNewsletter from '../../../components/SectionNewsletter'; //client component
import StyledLanding from '../styles'; //client component

export default function Landing() {
  return (
    <>
      <MetaHead></MetaHead>
      <PageLoadingWrapper>
        <StyledLanding>
          <SectionWrapper span={24} color={'light'}>
            <SectionHero />
          </SectionWrapper>

          <SectionWrapper span={24} color={'light'}>
            <LandingContent />
          </SectionWrapper>

          <SectionWrapper span={24} color={'light'}>
            <SectionFeatures />
          </SectionWrapper>

          <SectionWrapper span={24} color={'light'}>
            <SectionPlans />
          </SectionWrapper>

          <SectionWrapper span={24} color={'light'}>
            <SectionReferences />
          </SectionWrapper>

          <SectionWrapper span={24} color={'light'}>
            <SectionBlog />
          </SectionWrapper>

          <SectionWrapper span={24} color={'lightGrey'}>
            <SectionNewsletter />
          </SectionWrapper>
        </StyledLanding>
      </PageLoadingWrapper>
    </>
  );
}

and here is the network section screen shot:
network section with server component
As you can see it sends 237 requests and uses 99 mb resources. However, when I use "use client" in the page.tsx, which means making this page client component, it uses less resources and sends less requests.
network section with client component
Now it sends 174 requests and uses 66.7 mb.
How is this possible? Did I miss something about RSC?
These are my dependencies:
"dependencies": {
"@ant-design/colors": "^7.0.2",
"@ant-design/cssinjs": "^1.20.0",
"@ant-design/icons": "^5.3.6",
"@ant-design/nextjs-registry": "^1.0.0",
"@commitlint/config-conventional": "^18.6.3",
"@commitlint/cz-commitlint": "^18.6.1",
"@next/bundle-analyzer": "^14.2.3",
"@sanity/block-content-to-react": "^3.0.0",
"@sanity/client": "^6.15.20",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
"antd": "^5.16.4",
"axios": "^1.6.8",
"commitizen": "^4.3.0",
"commitlint": "^18.6.1",
"cross-env": "^7.0.3",
"crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
"framer-motion": "^10.18.0",
"hamburger-react": "^2.5.0",
"humps": "^2.0.1",
"husky": "^8.0.3",
"jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
"lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
"next": "14.0.4",
"next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
"next-sanity": "^9.0.10",
"next-sitemap": "^4.2.3",
"polished": "^4.3.1",
"prettier": "^3.2.5",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-country-flag": "^3.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-markdown": "^9.0.1",
"remark-gfm": "^4.0.0",
"server-only": "^0.0.1",
"sharp": "^0.33.3",
"styled-components": "^6.1.8",
"suspend-react": "^0.1.3",
"swiper": "^11.1.1",
"swr": "^2.2.5",
"usehooks-ts": "^2.16.0"

},
Thank you in advance.

can you try this comparison again in production mode

@ṽïηøṧ now server component uses 50 requests and client uses 55 request. what are the differences between prod and dev?

the development mode is made to ease your development experience, it compiles the code a bit differently so that it can enable the fast-refresh feature, it decomposes your files in a different way
however, the production mode is made to maximize and optimize the performance
idk how exactly things works under the hood but you might find smth in their docs
